Vacuum full Out of Memory Error PostgreSQL
I have some large tables in my database that I need to perform a FULL VACUUM but keep getting out of memory error. I am not sure what is the problem.
Memory parameters:
-free -g = 23
-shared buffer = 16GB

maintenance_work_mem = 2400MB

Below is the error I am getting:
postgres=# vacuum FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE client.patient118;
    INFO:  vacuuming "client.patient118"
    INFO:  "patient118": found 8852 removable, 50650355 nonremovable row versions in 
    993767 pages
    DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
    CPU: user: 282.17 s, system: 12.48 s, elapsed: 295.29 s.
    ERROR:  out of memory
    DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 16 in memory context "Caller tuples"
    CONTEXT:  parallel worker code
    

